# Blender Armature/Rig exported, without Bones but with Animations (to Unity)

Tags: armature, export, bones, unity

When I export my rig from Blender to Unity the bones under my characters armature vanish. Animations are listed and work as generic.

I can't reconfigure the rig, because Unity doesn't find the bones.(edited)
as you can see there should be a regular armature. But below, in Unity, the armature has no children...

Anyone any ideas as to why?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you check your export options.

It should look something like this :

[image: export options]

Comment: And I forgot to check "Only Deform Bones" in the armature export options.